# forEach() iteration without defining method

Tags: dart

Sorry about the confusing title, but i don't really know how to summarize this question.

Classes inheriting `Iterable` in Dart have a `forEach()` method. While they are nice and easy to use, I'm often in the situation where I'd like to do a small number of operations with the value, without the need to define a method for it, to improve the code's readability. Like PHP's `foreach` syntax, for example. So instead of writing:

```dart
void main() {  
  List<int> l = [1, 2, 3];
  l.forEach(doSomethingWithValue);
}

void doSomethingWithValue(int val) {
  String str = getStringFor(val);
  print(str);
}
```

I'd like to write something like this:

```dart
l.forEach((val) => {
  String str = getStringFor(val);
  print(str);
});
```

Of course, this code doesn't work, but I hope it demonstrates what I want to do. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're actually extremely close; you just need to get rid of the `=>`.  That's the syntax for a single-expression function body.  To define a function with multiple statements in the body, grouped within brackets, the bracketed body follows the parenthesized parameter list without `=>` in between:

```dart
l.forEach((val) {
  String str = getStringFor(val);
  print(str);
});
```

Note that this concept applies to named functions as well as to anonymous functions as in your example.

```dart
void doSomethingWithValue(int val) => print(val);
```

is the same as

```dart
void doSomethingWithValue(int val) {
  print(val);
}
```

Also note that a function body of the `=>` form returns the value of its expression:

```dart
int tripleValue(int val) => val * 3;
```

is the same as

```dart
int tripleValue(int val) {
  return val * 3;
}
```

Comment: Oh! And today I learned that `=>` is actually a well defined operator, not just an oddity. Thanks for the explanation.